# Delay on resize event on virtual keyboard on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, css, ios, mobile-safari

I'm working on an a webapp, where I need to adapt the contents of the screen when the virtual keyboard is expanded. Luckily, someone has already created an example of this here:

https://pmusaraj.github.io/ios15-bottom-bar2.html

When tapping on the text area, it correctly resizes. However, there is a small delay between the tap and when the resize happens in iOS 15.5. This is because the resize event doesn't seem to fire fully until after the keyboard is expanded. In iOS Chrome, interestingly, this does not happen and it works correctly.

Are there any workarounds to get Safari to fire the event sooner? Or alternative approaches to achieving a similar effect?

Answer (score 2):

As of today there are no real solutions for this.

The only "workaround" that I found is to detect when the keyboard opens and closes with regular events like `focus` and `blur`. But you can't guess the final visualViewport sizes because there are different keyboards so this wasn't an option for me.

My "solution" to this issue was extend the modal and its background fade beyond the viewport with `after` elements (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyThM.jpg)). That way there is still a jump between opening and closing the keyboard, but at least the look is a bit more consistent.